# How to do simple testing of a Laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In most web apps I've worked on, I can create a simple test script (test.php), load all dependencies (usually through an autoloader), setup the database connection, make calls to any class methods, then examine the results they return to make sure everything looks right.

Example:

```
$test = new Item;

var_dump($test->getItemStatus($itemid));
```

The above would show a nice output of the values it returns for that itemid.

With Laravel it appears to be much more complex to just perform this simple test...or maybe I am overcomplicating it and there is a simple way to do this.

Suppose I want to do the same thing in a Laravel 4 app. I want to test the output of method `getItemStatus` in controller named `ItemsController` that uses the model `Items`.

If I try the following, I get an `Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException` error:

```
$items = App::make('ItemsController')->getItemStatus($itemid);
```

If I define this route in routes.php:

```
Route::get('items/get-item-status', array('as' => 'getItemStatus', 'uses' => 'ItemsController@getItemStatus'));
```

Then try the following, I get `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException` in the request output:

```
$request = Request::create('items/get-item-status', 'GET', array());
$items = Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
```

Comment: What exactly you would like to test?

Comment: @dezco I'm modifying a controller's method to get some data from an external API. I need to have the method show the array of data it retrieved so I can validate it is coming through ok. To do that, I need to call the method in the controller...which always gives me `NotFoundHttpException` when I request the route in the test.php file I made. I have already defined the route in routes.php.

Comment: This for a starter http://laravel.com/docs/testing#calling-routes-from-tests, then this might direct you to your path (though it's not the best http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-laravel-controllers--net-31456)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion in Laravel is much more simple and maybe that's why you might be overthinking it.

Let's start with a very basic router. Here are some options to do simple debug using Laravel applications in a basic router/controller:

```
Route::get('test', function() {

    $test = new Item;

    dd($test);

    Log::info($test); // will show in your log

    var_dump($test);

});
```

Now follow:

```
http://yourserver.com/test
```

And it should stop on

```
dd($test);
```

Vardumping and dying at that line. Comment it, try again, and so on.

All of these will also work in a controller:

```
Route::get('test/{var?}', 'TestController@index');
```

The very same way:

```
class TestController extends Controller {

    public function index($var = null)
    {
        $test = new Item;

        dd($var);
        dd($test);

        Log::info($var);
        Log::info($test);

        var_dump($test);
        var_dump($var);
    }

}
```

Your route:

```
Route::get('items/get-item-status', array('as' => 'getItemStatus', 'uses' =>  'ItemsController@getItemStatus'));
```

Should also work, if you follow:

```
http://yourserver.com/items/get-item-status
```

If it doesn't, try to follow

```
http://yourserver.com/public/index.php/items/get-item-status
```

Or just

```
http://yourserver.com/public/items/get-item-status
```

Because you might have a virtual host or .htaccess configuration problem.

Comment: This only works when running `phpunit` from the command line. I need to show structured output in the web browser to fully debug and test my code. How do I run the code from within the browser so I can see the output of functions such as var_dump() etc from within that controller, or to be able to var_dump() what the controller returns?

Comment: Oh! Got it now, completely edited to show that it's really simple, var_dump() will work fine in Laravel.

Comment: Perfection! You are correct...I was overthinking it! Sleep deprivation will make everything look complicated. :)